# Highlight sentence feature with text-to-speech

Tags: productivity, text-to-speech

Up to now, text-to-speech (TTS) combined with highlighting sentences is by far the best way I found to read fast and at the same time very relaxed. I need an application or browser extension that enables highlighting sentences while reading them using text-to-speech (TTS) method.

I'm currently using TTS feature of Mac OSX but I really need this feature since I tested it with Moon+ Android App, for example, and facilitates a lot the reading. Basically, it allows you to read without directly reading each word, just visually follow sentence length.

Do anyone know any App for Mac or browsers extension? Thanks!

Comment: Do you like a browser plugin or do you want everything to be TTS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, finally I found what I was looking for.

http://www.chromevox.com/
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromevox/kgejglhpjiefppelpmljglcjbhoiplfn

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this is among the features of [Kurzweil reader](http://www.kurzweiledu.com/products/k3000-standalone.html). They offer a free trial, so you can see whether this is what you'd like.

Another solution is Apple's own [VoiceOver](https://www.apple.com/voiceover/info/guide/), which is built into the system. See especially the chapter on [Working With Text](https://www.apple.com/voiceover/info/guide/_1128.html).

Comment: I am very interested to find a solution to this. Could you possible elaborate how Apple's own VoiceOver can _highlighting sentences while reading them using text-to-speech (TTS) method_? I can't seem to find it in the chapter you are linking to. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. The basic idea is to register a `SpeechWordCFProcPtr` on the speech channel, do your own sentence splitting, and detect whether the word just being spoken has is overlapping a new sentence. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applicationservices/speechwordcfprocptr for documentation of the callback.