# MacOS highlight individual words as they are spoken, as iOS

Tags: macos, accessibility, text-to-speech

In iOS, it is possible to have the text read out loud using the built-in text-to-speech (TTS) while the individual words highlight as they are spoken.

Like in this gif:

[image: tts in iOS, MacOS highlight content as spoken as iOS]

(taken from [this you video](https://youtu.be/jXEYxEVGapo?t=163)).

I am looking for a way to get MacOS's (10.11) built-in TTS to highlight individual words as they are spoken, as in iOS. This is extremely helpful for me when reading.

[This Ask Different question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/124874/highlight-sentence-feature-with-text-to-speech) get at the same issue, but it's slightly different as it's asking for a browser-based solution and I am primarily looking for native MacOS solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

VoiceOver on macOS can do this.

1. Use **VoiceOver Utility.app** to activate *move highlight cursor by word*
2. Activate **VoiceOver** with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>
3. Click on the text you want to read
4. Press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to "read all"

[image: VoiceOver Utility - Visuals - move highlight by word]

How well it works will vary by application and how well they support VoiceOver.

> These animations were recorded on 10.13.6 High Sierra, but VoiceOver has been around since 10.4 Tiger - so you should be OK in 10.11 El Capitan.

Pages - works well

[image]

FSNotes - works well

[image]

Safari - depends on how the page is built

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response! I wasn't aware of the _VoiceOver Utility.app_ It it works, but as you also point out it _vary by application_ how how well VoiceOver works. I will keep the question open for a tidbit longer to see if anything else show up. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

You can try [Dictator](http://nosrac.github.io/Dictater/) by Nosrac.  It's available for free on GitHub.  I'm not the developer or affiliated with the software.
[image]

It has a feature called 'teleprompter mode' that highlights the words as they're spoken.

[image]

The code hasn't been updated in a few years and I haven't tried it myself so I can't speak for how well it works.  I'm recommending it because it looks like it does what you want and it's free.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately _Dictator by Nosrac_ do not seem to be working under MacOS 10.11. I did hope to find a native solution, but maybe that's not possible. Thanks.

Comment: Yea, I wasn't entirely sure it work with your version but I thought it was worth a shot.  I'm not aware of any native solution that does what you want.

Comment: Any chance you would be willing to rewrite your answer into a comment? I understand if you want to keep it as an answer, but I wanted to ask respectfully as it is my experience that questions _unaccepted_ gets less attention. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @EricFail.  While this answer might not address your specific situation, and therefore not be accepted, it might help others who have the same issue.  I've seen hundreds of unaccepted answers get comments from others who said it did help.  Based on that, I'll leave the answer alone (along with your comments as to why it wasn't accepted).

Comment: Upvote from me as it'll definitely help some users. :)

Comment: This should absolutely be and remain a full answer.

Comment: @Monomeeth and Wowfunhappy thank you for chiming in on this. I wonder if you have tried the software in question and if so under what MacOS? As mentioned above _Dictator by Nosrac do not seem to be working under MacOS 10.11._ Thanks.

Comment: @EricFail Thanks for your feedback. I have no doubt your question will appeal to users across multiple generations of Mac OS X / macOS, so the reason for my upvote is that I feel this answer will be useful for *some* of those users, although I appreciate at this stage it'll be limited to those on older versions of macOS.

Answer (score 0):

I tried an app called Natural Reader and it does a decent job, but the voices are terrible and it isn't quite as seamless as iOS's integration. I really only want this for Safari so I guess I'll just have to Airdrop the link to my nearby iPhone or iPad and initiate the screen reader gesture there. Natural Reader does have a great Chrome Extension so I am hoping with Big Sur and the new ability to easily port Chrome Extensions to Safari that they will do that soon and let us use all of the system voices; I much prefer the UK Male Safari voice to any of Natural Reader's voice, free and paid.